# combine two CONTAINS calls within where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create the following SQL query (as in, this is an example of the final query) :-

```
DECLARE @SearchQuery AS NVARCHAR(100) = 'yellow bird'

SELECT Id, Name
FROM dbo.FooBars
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, N'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, yellow)') 
  AND CONTAINS(Name, N'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, bird)')
```

Notice how I've got two `CONTAINS` lines? This is because the search query has two words in it. (a *space* is the delimiter). This query could be from 1 to n words.

How can I generate this SQL code based upon the number of words in the search query?

Comment: Have you tried just appending AND CONTAINS clauses for each searchword?

Comment: um.. not sure what you mean. Currently, the above is _not_ dynamic text that is created and then executed. it's sql code in a stored procedure.. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the "AND" in the contains itself, so it coud be

```
select * 
from dbo.FooBars
where contains(Name, 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, yellow) AND FORMSOF(Thesaurus, bird)')
```

with the string 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, yellow) AND FORMSOF(Thesaurus, bird)'
built up into a variable like

```
declare @searchCriteria varchar(200)
set @searchCriteria = 'Some string you built up'
select * 
from dbo.FooBars
where contains(Name, @searchCriteria)
```